# Prove a subset of polynomial is a vectorial subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to prove a subset V, is a vectorial subspace. The given subset V is:

[image: link]

I know a subset to be a subspace must respect the following rules:

- It must include {O}
- Addition closure
- Multiplication closure

I don't know how can I pick a generic polynomial to prove what I am asked to do.

Comment: A vector space is a commutative group under addition and is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Wuestenfux How can I show this? I thought about generic vectors of the subset but I don't know how can I choose them and if this is correct

Comment: Given a polynomial p(n) = a + bn +cn^2+... show that if you add two polynomials I still get a polynomial of this form. (hint: put terms with exponents next to each other) and if you multiply by a scalar c then you still have a polynomial of that same form. (hint: nothing changes except the value of you coefficients)

Comment: You need to show that with two vectors, the sum is in there, with one vector $v$ the inverse $-v$ and the scalar multiple $av$, $a$ a scalar, are in there. If you can do this by taking generic elements, the better.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $p\in V$ then, it must be of the form $p(x)=(x+1)g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a real polynomial with degree at most $2$

So basically each vector in $V$ is nothing but a polynomial of the form stated above.

Now that you know how the vectors look, you can test whether it is a subspace or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- {O} is included because p(-1)=0

  - k ∈ V, k*p(x) = k(ax^2+bx+c) = kax^2+kbx+kc which is closed to multiplication
- g(x), p(x) ∈ V with p(x) = ax^2+bx+c, g(x) = dx^2+ex+f,

  -the sum of g(x)+p(x)= (a+d)x^2+(b+e)x+c+f which is again in V